# Why ActionResult method doesn't take any parameter from Html.BeginForm() inside view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I tried to make a database named PersonalJobManagement and it includes information of my employees.
I would like to code an ASP.NET MVC website to edit, delete or create new data for this database.

But here is the problem:
I write the create view, I enter parameters like name or id, but parameters're not processed into the database. There are 8 employees added already and I cannot add the 9th.

My Create Methods in Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Person model)
{
     db.Person.Add(model);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

My Create View:

```
       @using (Html.BeginForm())
       {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           <div>
               <div>
                   <b>Name</b>
                   <div>
                       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new {} })
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new {})
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div>
                   <div>
                       <input type="submit" value="Save it"/>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       }
```

And my Person model:

```
public partial class Person
   {
       public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }
       public string PersonType { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string MiddleName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public System.DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
   
       public virtual BusinessEntity BusinessEntity { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Does your application report about any errors? Can you include definition of the `Person` model to the post?

Comment: @Jackdaw Nope, there is no error, i added breakpoint to curly brace after `public ActionResult Create(Person model)` to see what happens but program didn't reach there

Comment: You mean that nothing happens when you click the submit button, right?

Comment: Do you have another form in form?If you see devtools Network,can you see a request of Create,if you can see it,what is the status code of it.

Comment: @Tomato32 , yes, unfortunately nothing happens...

Comment: @YiyiYou, under networks tab, it says `Request Method: GET, Status Code: 200`

Comment: So you go to the method `public ActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}`?If you use `<form method="post"></form>` rather than `@using (Html.BeginForm())` Can you work?

Comment: @YiyiYou, nothing changed dude, why it goes to `GET`, instead of `POST`

Comment: When you click the button,you will only get  a get request?maybe the get request you said is the request to load the page.

Comment: @YiyiYou, yeap, when i clicked to the button, it refreshes page, probably it requests to load page, how can i change it?

Comment: @Kerem Yavuz: Try to use overloaded `Html.BeginForm()` helper method `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)` to specify the **POST** request. The problem you don't reach the `public ActionResult Create(Person model)` with the `[httppost]` attribute because of the model binding does not work from some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAILED IT!
My `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file has a form tag and i don't know why but it causes the error when calling `POST` method. So if you are here, be careful guys